# Trigger is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

```
    <div id="divuploadpic">
    <form name="uploader" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="uploadedpic" id="uploadedpic" style="display: none;" />
         <input type="submit" name="submituploadedpic" id="submituploadedpic" />
    </form>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#divuploadpic").click(function(){
        $("#uploadedpic:hidden").trigger('click');
     });
});
</script>
```

I have hidden the input file tag and `onclicking` the `div` , it should be `triggered.$("#divuploadpic").click(function()` works fine But the trigger is not working here. How to resolve it?

Comment: better use for `label` tag

Answer (score 2):

**For my suggestion:**

better use for [**`label`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) tag instead of `div` its perform without js

```html
<label id="divuploadpic" for="uploadedpic">click
  <form name="uploader" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedpic" id="uploadedpic"  style="display:none"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submituploadedpic" id="submituploadedpic" />
  </form>
</label>
```

Comment: This is a good idea if there is nothing more in the `div` than text. [HTML Label specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) recommends using it only when [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a handler function for the click on `#uploadedpic`. See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$(function(){
    $("#divuploadpic").click(function(){
        $("#uploadedpic:hidden").trigger('click');
     });
});
$('#uploadedpic').on('click', function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log('clicked');
});
```

```css
#divuploadpic {
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divuploadpic">
    <form name="uploader" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="uploadedpic" id="uploadedpic" style="display: none;" />
         <input type="submit" name="submituploadedpic" id="submituploadedpic" />
    </form>
</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/0943r1zj/1/).

**EDIT**

If there is nothing more in the `div` than text in your `div` element, see [prasad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413268/4726671). [HTML Label specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) recommends using labels only when [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is expected.